# NoneType object has no attribute json - Office365 file upload using Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests, office365-rest-client

I am trying to use the Office365-REST module to upload a file to Sharepoint.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.creation_information import FileCreationInformation
import traceback

try:
    fullurl = 'https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/'
    fileName = 'c:/temp/upload.zip'
    rootfolder = 'Documents'
    targetfolder = '/PythonTests/'

    ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=fullurl)
    if  ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id='redacted', client_secret='redacted'):
        ctx = ClientContext(fullurl, ctx_auth)
        target_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(rootfolder)
        info = FileCreationInformation()
        with open(fileName, 'rb') as content_file:
            info.content = content = content_file.read()
        info.url = fileName
        info.overwrite = True
        upload_file = target_list.root_folder.files.add(fileName.split("/")[-1], info.content, overwrite=True)
        ctx.execute_query()
except:
    traceback.print_exc()

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'
  File "C:\scripts\upload_to_sharepoint.py", line 20, in <module>
    ctx.execute_query()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Python\Office365-REST\upload_to_sharepoint.py", line 22, in <module>
    ctx.execute_query()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 181, in execute_query
    self.pending_request().execute_query(qry)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 58, in execute_query
    response = self.execute_request_direct(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 70, in execute_request_direct
    self.beforeExecute.notify(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\types\event_handler.py", line 21, in notify
    listener(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 221, in _build_modification_query     
    self._ensure_form_digest(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 157, in _ensure_form_digest
    self._ctx_web_info = self._get_context_web_information()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 170, in _get_context_web_information  
    client.map_json(response.json(), return_value, json_format)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'
```

I noticed that the **request.auth** was `None`, and there are no headers listed in **request.headers** when the post is made to the `/contextInfo` URL.  However, I am authenticated according to the `AuthenticationContext` return.  I'm also successfully getting the `target_list`. I'm unsure where to go from here.  Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Updated the code above based on the suggestion for `{fullurl}` on line 14.
I decided to use the Graph API Explorer to test some methods and noticed a couple of items which may be influencing this issue.  First, when I do a GET request to the site drives, there is nothing in the values list.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/drives

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": []
}
```

Without identifying a drive, the library name wouldn't resolve, correct?

If I try to retrieve the details of the default drive, I get access is denied.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/SiteName:/drive

{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "Access denied",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-08-01T16:49:31",
            "request-id": "9b9b9ff7-cd93-4a55-8f8c-14035c3f03e2",
            "client-request-id": "f0761f22-91af-8740-cdfa-987715aeab89"
        }
    }
}
```

I am not the owner of the Sharepoint group, so I believe the issue stems from my permisisons.  I am working to get elevated permissions to see if that addresses anything.

**EDIT #2**

Following the suggestion to use a more recent version of the API, I updated and tried the following, but still received the JSON error.

```
import os

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential


def print_upload_progress(offset):
    file_size = os.path.getsize(local_path)
    print("Uploaded '{0}' bytes from '{1}'...[{2}%]".format(offset, file_size, round(offset / file_size * 100, 2)))


ctx = ClientContext('https://org.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/').with_credentials(ClientCredential(client_id='redacted', client_secret='redacted'))

target_url = "Shared Documents/PythonTests"
target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(target_url)
size_chunk = 1000000
local_path = "c:/temp/upload.zip"
with open(local_path, 'rb') as f:
    uploaded_file = target_folder.files.create_upload_session(f, size_chunk,
                                                              print_upload_progress).execute_query()

print('File {0} has been uploaded successfully'.format(uploaded_file.serverRelativeUrl))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Python\Office365-REST\upload_to_sharepoint_user_updated.py", line 24, in <module>
    uploaded_file = target_folder.files.create_upload_session(f, size_chunk,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_object.py", line 44, in execute_query
    self.context.execute_query()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 181, in execute_query
    self.pending_request().execute_query(qry)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 57, in execute_query
    response = self.execute_request_direct(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 69, in execute_request_direct
    self.beforeExecute.notify(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\types\event_handler.py", line 21, in notify
    listener(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 222, in _build_modification_query
    self._ensure_form_digest(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 157, in _ensure_form_digest
    self._ctx_web_info = self._get_context_web_information()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\client_context.py", line 171, in _get_context_web_information
    client.map_json(response.json(), return_value, json_format)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'
```

The same error is thrown.  I did some more digging and I noticed this site is made from a Microsoft Team, and now I'm wondering if the structure of a Sharepoint Site made by Teams differs from a non-Team site?

**EDIT #3**

I have replicated the issue on a completely different Sharepoint site, and ruled out the possibility it was because Teams created a site.  We tested on new sites created both ways in the second Sharepoint site, and still there are issues with the request being made from the module.  At this point, I am looking to change to PowerShell and hope this get around the issues that are being presented by the Office365 module.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - Answer irrelevant, OP updated the code, still having issues.

---

On line 14, instantiating `ClientContext`, a literal `{fullurl}` is provided as the first argument, while an actual URL is expected there (e.g. `https://org.sharepoint.com/...`).

To provide it with the actual URL as provided to `AuthenticationContext`, simply remove the single-quotation marks (`'`) and the curly-brackets (`{}`), like so:

```
        ctx = ClientContext(fullurl, ctx_auth)
```

In case that f-string parsing is somehow required (although not demonstrated in the question) - an `f` should be prepended to the literal string, like so:

```
        ctx = ClientContext(f'{fullurl}', ctx_auth)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I made the suggested modifications, but the same `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'` is thrown when executing the query.  The ClientContext doesn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: Although passing an invalid URL will definitely cause problems, I've also noticed that you're using a very old API (from over 3 years ago). While minor releases should technically maintain backwards-compatibility (at least according to [standards](https://semver.org/)), it is not inconceivable that older APIs were phased-out, either by neglect or by intent, by the package's maintainer or by Microsoft Corporation. `ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)` was removed from the package's docs in May 2020, and `.with_credentials()` was introduced the following June. [continuing in next comment..]

Comment: Take a look at the latest upload examples for [small](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload.py) and [large](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload_large.py) files. Make sure your environment's packages are up-to-date, and try adapting to the new API. Keep us posted on the progress :)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I tried using the same structure of the upload_large.py example you mentioned, but still have the same error.  I also noted that the Sharepoint site was created from Teams and now I am wondering if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Can you add the new traceback? Even if it also starts from the `execute_query()`, it might shed some more light on the origin. Possibly even by comparing to the previous TB. At this point it's just guesswork on my end, but it can only help..

Comment: Traceback added.